# Get various coordinates for touches in swift

Tags: swift, touchesbegan

Im trying to get the coordinates of various points when touching in a UIView for swift 4. I've seen the other post regarding a similar problem, but that code only allows the first touch to be registered. I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you coordinates for every time you touch the screen. You can test it by print it out or put it straight in to a label.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var coordinates = CGPoint.zero

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first{
        coordinates = touch.location(in: imageView)
        print(coordinates)
        textLabel.text = "\(coordinates)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I was also able to find an answer for my question: I used the code bellow inside of a UIViewController to get a 2d array of integers when touching in different locations. Thanks for all the help.

```
var positionArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 10)
    var counter = 0
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: self.view)
            let locx = Int(position.x)
            let locy = Int(position.y)
                positionArray[counter] = [locx, locy]
                print(positionArray[counter])
                counter = counter + 1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the touchesMoved callback on your UIView subclass to do this.

```
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

This function gets called repeatedly while the touch is ongoing.

Here's the general idea:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    print("x = \(location.x), y = \(location.y)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work when you stop touching and then touch in another place?

Comment: Yes. If you stop touching then you get a touchesEnded callback (if you have implemented it). Then when you touch another place you get a touchesBegan and then more touchesMoved.

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21317141. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a short heads up, I will quickly delete this comment.

Comment: Hi, ncke. I gave the mark to Daniel because of the more detailed explanation -and because I apparently don't know how to use a touchesEnded-, but they both appear to work.